# Make inputAccessoryView look like default Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

I have created a inputAccessoryView with numbers on it, I have that everything working just fine. I would like it to look and act like the iOS default keyboard. What would be the best way todo that? I have looked all over online for what colors to use but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the colors you want would be to capture the screen while they keyboard is visible. You could then look at the screenshot with the tool of your choice to get the colors for individual pixels.